# How Do I align a tcl code in vi editor using 4 spaces as the stantard?

Tags: alignment, vi

I wanted to know if the customized tab of 4 spaces will work with alignment present in vi editor . When I try to align by selecting using v and aligning using  ">>" , I get an alignment with the default of 8 spaces which is unacceptable to me .

Answer (score 0):

Possible you need to reconfigure the tabstop in your .vimrc file.

See the description here: [Indent with tabs, align with spaces](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indent_with_tabs,_align_with_spaces)

Answer (score 0):

I use these settings for Tcl in vim:

```
set autoindent
set shiftwidth=4
set shiftround
set comments=:#
set cindent
set cinkeys-=0#
set smarttab
set expandtab   " I like spaces not tabs
```

You can put these in `~/.vimfiles/ftplugin/tcl.vim` to set the automatically for *.tcl files.

Help available for all, example `:help 'cindent'` in command mode.